# In Maze Runner book 3, why doesn't Frypan try to get out of the Maze?

Tags: the-maze-runner

In Maze Runner Book 3 - The Death Cure, at the end, Thomas gets to know (from Ava Paige) that W.I.C.K.E.D has once again started with the Maze Trials. So, he comes to save them. There in the Maze, Thomas spots Frypan (who was originally with Thomas in the first Maze Trials) and even Frypan recognizes Thomas. That leads to 2 questions

1. Why didn't W.I.C.K.E.D. wipe the memory of Frypan again before sending him back to the Maze
2. Since Frypan still has his memory, why doesn't he try to escape from the Maze? Why does he still stay in the maze to undergo the trials?

Answer (score -1):

wicked didn't wipe frypans memory because if the vivisection worked there would be no point and he didn't try to escape because he thought that the grievers would kill him

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I don't see how this explains why W.I.C.K.E.D. didn't wipe his memory before sending him back into the Maze.  Obviously they can't kill him before sending him back, so your answer is a bit of a non-sequitur.